# Remove version from appStore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have my app on app store with version 1.2 with status ready for sale.I want release new version 1.2.1 on app store but by mistake i have created 12.1 version.so is there any way to remove this version and create new version.

Comment: yes make sure your version in xcode that will reflect to the app store automatically.

Comment: how do you mean _remove_? the users who installed v1.2 and they don't want to update they will have v1.2 until they delete it or update it (you can't remove the app from their device forcibly); meanwhile the new users basically gets the latest available version on the platform they use; meanwhile you can update the version number before it goes to sale; what is your question about actually?

Comment: you can cancel a build thats been submitted in itunes connect, and then just upload the new version with the correct version number. Should fix the issue for you. There should be a cancel this release link at the top of the page. See the screenshot provided below by Pranav on where to change build numbers. If you have actually released a version at 12.1 then you cant change i dont think

Comment: @holex she has createed 12.1 version in itunesconnect by mistake and she wants to realse 1.2.1 so how to chage it .

Comment: @Scriptable she has not released 12.1 if she has she can not change in that case. you are correct. I am assuming that

Comment: i have rejected version 12.1 before ready for sale so it's status is developer rejected . so i am just want get rid of 12.1 version

Comment: @ShipraGupta then just realse new one with new build number. You cant remove that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by just updating version number available below app icon of my app and save it .as shown in the screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As image shown below set your version in xcode and upload app to iTunesConnect that will change automatically.

[image]